# How to prevent CouchDB to create document revisions when updating simple counters

Tags: javascript, couchdb

I want to store counters in a CouchDB document, incremented on each page view.
CouchDB will create a complete revision of this document for just 1 counter update.

Wouldn't this consume too much space?
Considering that I have 1M hits in a day, I might be looking at 1M revisions to the document in a day.

Any thoughts on this...

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

CouchDB is very explicit about the trade-offs it makes. In this particular case, we are talking about having a crash proof database that, sadly, can and will use a lot of disk until compaction.

You get with this reliability and a lot concurrency for reads. You will also get the ability to replicate seamlessly with any other nodes. This is the bacon of it. Having to compact because of bumped counters is the suck of it. Forget about mucking around with _rev_limit. You will screw yourself doing it because revisions are so foundational to Couch.

One possibility that you have is logging some info, the date and time, IP's and other stuff. You'd then create a view emitting the data you need and using _count as your reduce function. You'll get the info you need and some other possibly valuable stuff for analytics. This is the "just create a view" solution.

The second possibility would be using [redis] (http://redis.io/commands/incr). Redis is quite nice and would fit well with this use case (http://ai.mee.nu/is_couchdb_the_anti-redis). This would be the "the right tool for the right job" solution.

The third possibility would be to simply ignore it. It might not be a problem at all (if you compact often). This would be the "just relax" solution.

You have to take the good with the bad and make sure the advantages outweighs the disadvantages. Measure everything twice before you cut/optimize.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think it's possible.

An alternative solution would be to place the counter in a small document, and run [compaction](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Compaction) on it periodically. This isn't optimal, but it minimizes the space occupied.

Comment: I agree, but I think there should be a better way around this problem. I am exploring limiting revisions to a given document. Will update this question with my findings...

Comment: Some research reveals this thread - http://www.mail-archive.com/couchdb-user@incubator.apache.org/msg01974.html

Comment: If a database is configured with _revs_limit=1, will the Conflict resolution & Changes feed still work? Hypothetically, to maintain an incrementing counter, we can have such a key/value pair in the document whose database is configured with _revs_limit = 1

Thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: I think _revs_limit is only used during compaction, to keep _revs_limit revisions. During the normal use, no revision deletion will be done.

Comment: I'm not an expert (but I'm getting there) but I do know that conflict resolution and changes feeds will still work with revs_limit=1, but you do lose some of the functionality of merging changes on conflict.

Answer (score 2):

You may also want to consider using something like memcached (or Membase) to serve as your "counter storage".  That will let you update these counters without creating extra revisions in CouchDB.  I assume that you don't actually need to keep all of the intermediate states of the counter (since you say that you don't want the revisions kept around) so putting them in something better suited for this use case seems to make sense.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need replication you can save the Counter in a _local doc. 
Local documents do not have a version history. 
You also can save them without knowing their revision. 
They don't replicate, last write wins always.

To create/update a _local doc just use `PUT /db/_local/[DOCID]`

You can retrieve your _local doc with `GET /db/_local/[DOCID]`

Answer (score 1):

We were doing a little experiment...

The document had default 1000 revs limit, had about 100kb of attachments, 1 integer counter, which we kept incrementing

We ended up with about 4GB of disk used for about 200,000 increments. Used compaction & it got reduced to about 6KB.

Now that's a bummer!

My serious concerns are now - running frequent compaction (maybe hourly/twice-daily/etc) on a write heavy couch instance!