# CouchDb : How to combine query and update requests into one?

Tags: couchdb

The structure of my couchDb documents is like this

**Posts**

```
 {
      _id : '123132adsf',
    'userId' :'7236jsdfkaf',
     'Title' : 'This is a sample post'
}
```

**User**

```
{
   '_id' : '7236jsdfkaf',
   'count' : 1
}
```

The functionality that I am looking for is whenever the *posts* document is queried using the *posts* view the count field in the *user* that owns the post is updated.Is there any way to do this with a single couchDb request or will I have to make two requests to the database one for query and one for updation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it if you knew apriori the id of the post. You can use [update function](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Document_Update_Handlers) to change the value of the `viewed` field to `1` in the post document and return the data of the post. It is dirty hack, though. Instead the `count` in the user document you would use then the reduced sum of the `viewed` for the user. The thing is that, you have to know the id of the post before, because update function cannot do arbitrary query - it modifies the document it is given.

Comment: This changes a `GET`/view to a `PUT`/`POST`, which makes for an unusual non-traditional Restful API.

Comment: I also added a few more details in my answer suggesting why doing this another way still might be a better choice.

Answer (score 2):

Strictly speaking, when reading from a view, you'll need to add the functionality elsewhere.

In CouchDB, you'd need to be able to read the User document (and revision), and set that back during the read-only View operation.

Document `get` requests cannot affect (or even read) other documents during a read (views are read-only as well). Reads are intended to be cacheable for a given document version. Even the `show` ([docs](http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/show.html)) and `list` functionality of CouchDB prevents this from happening.

**Other notes:**

Also, consider the issue of CouchDB not necessarily being the best option for doing auto-incrementing fields. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7388058/how-to-prevent-couchdb-to-create-document-revisions-when-updating-simple-counter)'s a good StackOverflow answer that details some of the challenges you might face. In essence, you may find that due to the way revisions of documents are managed in CouchDB, that frequent counter incrementing (such as you need), without frequent database compaction could lead to excessive disk utilization. Other systems may be better for doing page-view counting.

If you used the suggestion of using an `Update` function ([docs](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Document_Update_Handlers)), you've made caching pages/posts more expensive and require the CouchDB instance always return a revised document/post, every time the post is requested, which is very unnecessary (and should be cached on a web-tier if possible).

Comment: You make good points and redis could be a good choice.The problem is the rest of my architecture is really well suited to couchDb and with it I have really good providers in iris couch and cloudant to provide hosting.Would it make sense to use two databases couchDb for storing the data and redis for incrementing fields and logging stuff?Is there a good(read free (:) provider for redis.If I decide to go with it where can host it?

Comment: Also I am open to any other no sql database that you might want to suggest.Thanks :)

Comment: If you're not self hosting, I'd speculate you'll pay a lot for hosting given the way you're writing. Cloudant for example costs 5x as much for writes over reads. I've not looked into free hosts for Redis.